# Image Button for Xamarin.MacOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, imagebutton

Is there an Image Button Renderer in Xamarin.MacOS?
I am using Xamarin.Forms and all my image buttons in the common code are not shown at all in Xamarin.MacOS.  Is Image Button supported in Xamarin.MacOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an Image Button Renderer in Xamarin.MacOS?

**Unfortunately**, after checking the source code of **Xamarin.Forms.Platform.macOS**, there is no `ImageButtonRenderer` there now. I guess the reason that there is no control is the similar with `ImageButton`. I'm not sure whehter designer will add this in the future. Whatever, now it not exists.

> Is Image Button supported in Xamarin.MacOS?

From the above said, **MacOS** has no control like `ImageButton` of Forms. Therefore, if used ImageButton in Xamarin Froms, it will not show in Xamarin.MacOS.

However, there is a workaround. You could use `Button` in Forms, and add Image in `ButtonRenderer` in Xamarin.MacOS. Because `NSButton` has a [Image property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/appkit.nsbutton.image?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14).

For example, the code of ButtonRenderer as follows:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(MyButton), typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.MacOS
{
    public class MyButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (Control != null) {
                // do whatever you want to the UITextField here!
                Control.Image= NSImage.ImageNamed("tree")
                Control.ImageScaling = NSImageScale.AxesIndependently;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The image source (`tree.png`) is the same way with iOS to be added in **Resource** folder, and set ***Propertied : Build Action -> BundleResource***.

Comment: I am referring to "Image Button" and not "Button".  Image Button is to display image rather than text and can support OnClick event handler.  Currently, on my Mac for Xamarin.Forms, no image is shown at all.

Comment: @TekMun Sorry for providing the suggestion of Button. I will check the ImageButton, if good ideas will update the answer.

Comment: @TekMun Hi, I have updated the answer, you could have a look when have time.

Comment: @Jiang Thanks for the speedy update.  In Xamarin.Forms, the location of the image is stored in ImageSource.  Hence, NSImage.ImageNamed cannot be used directly. For iOS, the workaround is to use ImageSource to UIImage (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/112460/#Comment_112460)  Is there a similar method for ImageSource to NSImage?

Comment: @TekMun Although not haing a workaroud now, but I think it's possible. We could create a custom `Button` in Forms with a custom property(`ImageSource`),then convert the `ImageSource` with `byte[]` to MacOS, then `NSImage.FromStream(xxx)` could show the Image.

Comment: @TekMun Sorry, there is no sample code now. Later if have will update here.

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT i occur the same issue here, i did you find a solution ? can we have a sample here ?

Comment: @A.Caillet Hi, you could create a new question in SO, and detail the problems. Then can share the link here, I will check that and other people also will see that to help you.